# count turtles in patches above current patch NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am currently trying to implement a function into my [netlogo](/questions/tagged/netlogo) code that will count the number of turtles above the current patch and set it to a variable denoted `n`. I have set the patches to be only one, ten-patch tall column at `pxcor = 0`.

My function doesn't work because I need to input a reporter instead of a variable but I just cannot think of a way to circumvent this issue. My code is as follows:

```
let n count turtles-on patches with [pycor > pycor of myself ]
```

If anyone has any experience with this issue or knows how to code for this, your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
let n count turtles-on patches with [pycor > [pycor] of myself ]
```

Works for me.

```
let n count turtles-on patches with [pycor > [pycor] of myself and xcor = [xcor] of myself ]
```

if you want only the ones directly above the calling turtle and there are more turtles about. The error is because of the lack of brackets.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much. I really should have caught that but thank you for your help.

Comment: oh not your fault the old style was pycor-of and old habits and such.